# Element not found {input[type='file']} при запуске в Selenoid на удаленном сервере

Tags: java, test-automation, cucumber, selenoid

Всем привет! При запуске тест кейсов локально на ПК, все работает. При запуске на Selenoid на удаленном сервере, на шаге загрузки файла ошибка Element not found {input[type='file']} и файл не загружается.

Пример input на странице

```
<input type="hidden" xpath="1">
<input type="file" class="gwt-FileUpload" accept="null" name="28662_file" xpath="1">
```

Пример класса реализации степа

public void uploadFile(String fileName)  throws AWTException  {

```
    String file = new File("data/" + fileName).getAbsolutePath();
    log.info("===>>> load file path: {}", file);
    sleep(5000);
    pageMap.getSelectedPage("общая страница").getElements("загрузить файл").sendKeys(file);
    sleep(5000);
в настройке remote web driver
```

public WebDriver webDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

```
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
    capabilities.setVersion("87.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("enableVNC", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("enableVideo", false);
    capabilities.setCapability("resolution", "1920x1080");
    capabilities.acceptInsecureCerts();
    capabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/"),
            capabilities
    );
    driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

    com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration.timeout = 8000;
    WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
    return WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой. Сначала пытался повлиять на этот input, например, присвоением ему значения display=block вместо none, так же проверил наличие driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

Однако решение я нашёл в том, что мои файлы, которые я загружаю, необходимо было переименовать с русского на английский язык, после этого проблема решилась. Понял, что надо было внимательнее изучить лог ошибки, там была строка "unable to unzip 'file'", по которой я нашел данный вопрос и ответ:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050742/webdriverexception-unknown-error-unable-to-unzip-file-when-i-attached-file-w

Удачи!